Why vue keepalive not work when a div inside?
Why does this div stop the keep-alive from working?
<keep-alive>
  <div>
    <suspense>
      <component :is＝"Component">
    </suspense>
  </div>
</keep-alive>

When I put the div inside the suspense the situation is even worse because the project while collapse when the component changes (I have an async component)

<keep-alive> expects <component> as the default slot, change to:
<div>
  <keep-alive>
    <suspense>
      <component :is＝"Component">
    </suspense>
  </keep-alive>
</div>


is suspense the same？ I don't understand why there is a div because that's spelled by my officer

@肉蛋充肌 my guess the suspense is the same

Thanks, but I want to know the reason behind this, like "keep-alive  on accept component because its' code depends on some attributes of componet  rather than a html tag"

@肉蛋充肌 keep-alive expects a component returned with its default slot, if you put <div> keep-alive stop caring because <div> isn't a component but an element, so it doesn't analyze its children
